# Having multiple 'sub-repositories' in one git repository?

Tags: git, github

I was fortunate enough to obtain a free micro-plan Github account to use for my schoolwork through Github's EDU program. However, I am not sure how best to structure this for my CS classes. Ideally, I would have a different repository for each class -- CS101, CS102, etc. However, the micro-plan only allows up to 5 repositories, and I will be taking more than 5 classes within the next year or two. So, is there a way to structure one repository to keep commits 'separate' for each folder, i.e. have one repository with multiple 'sub'-repositories (basically a submodule).

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: But then the commits would interfere with each other. I would like to have one stream of commits per directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Branching

For each class, run within the repository `git checkout --orphan <classname>`, and you can get a new parentless branch for that class's content.

When getting local copies of your repository, run `git clone --single-branch --branch <classname> <url> <localdir>`, and it will only clone and later fetch that class's branch.

#### Bitbucket

As trauzti said, I would definitely recommend a Bitbucket account.  While the UI isn't as pretty as Github's, it has all the same functionality, and they do allow free unlimited private repositories.  I use it for my schoolwork.  If you really want to use Github though, then the above would work.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could have orphans in Git... Also, I like Bitbucket so a +1 for the whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone knows a way to use submodules for this: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

You could use multiple branches, one branch for each class, and check out the different branches in different directories on your computer.

But if there are only 5 people or less going to be using these repositories you should check out BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/

There you can have an infinite number of private repositories for free.

Comment: But don't submodules require there to be another repository? Or is it possible to create a 'local' submodule?

Comment: Yes it seems that way, but you could of course use multiple branches, some documentation on branches here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: Submodules wouldn't work for this.  A submodule is a way to reference a *separate* repository from within another.

Branching is probably the way to go.